# Significance and implication of Mahout's death

Tags: plot-explanation, hey-ram

After the Calcutta violence scene in [Hey Ram](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0222012/), Saket Ram saw the *mahout* (elephant's caretaker) dead and that the elephant could not move. I think it was chained. Does this imply anything? Why did the director (Kamal Hassan) make those scenes?

Answer (score 2):

I think it implies something.

When Saket sees the elephant, the first thing he notices is it standing alone. After a brief moment of confusion, he sees its caretaker lying dead beside it and realises the poor creature is completely lost without its mahout. It has been under his direction for so long it doesn't know how to cope on its own.

This really does appear to affect Saket, as you notice. It likely reminds him of what is happening in his life. Until this point, Saket had had his wife. With her killed, he feels both helpless and alone.

Realising the elephant's situation echoes his alone, he breaks down.